# Trying to keep the CSS transform when I navigate in the menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

when I am not hovering my elem, it keep returns to his standard position, but I want it to stay when I am navigating in the menu "sousmenu", and keep returning on his original position when I am not hovering the "sousmenu". I am not very comfortable to create custom scripts for jquery, so I'm a little lost in this case. Thanks for your help!

```css
.line-menu{
 z-index: 10;
 display: list-item;
  background-color: #b6a083;
  height: 1px;
  width: 30px;
  font-size: 1px;
  padding: 1px;
  color: white;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-left: 15px;
 margin-top: 10px;
  opacity: .7;
}

.class-menu{
 position: relative;
 z-index: 10;
 display: block;
 margin-top: 50px;
 margin-left: 30px;
}

.class-menu:hover > .elem-one{
 animation: lag-down 0.2s;
 -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes lag-down {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    transform: translateY(13px);

  }
}

 .class-menu:hover > .elem-three{
 animation: lag-up 0.2s;
 -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 -moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
 @keyframes lag-up {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    transform: translateY(-13px);
  }
}

#menu{
    /*height: 21px;*/
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
#menu li a:hover {background-color: none;}
#menu li a:active {background-color: #FFF;}
#menu .sousMenu{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
    display: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 1px;
    line-height: 1.8;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-family: DidotBoldItalic;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
    /*opacity: 0.5;*/
    width: 290px;
    height: 690px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-top: 110px;
    border: 0;
}
#menu .sousMenu li{
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
#menu .sousMenu li a:link, #menu .sousMenu li a:visited{
display: block;
color: black;
font-family: 'Futura_light';
margin: 0;
border: 0;
text-decoration: none;
}
#menu .sousMenu li a:hover{
 background-image: none;
 color: #b6a083;
}
#menu li:hover > .sousMenu {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="menu">
     <li><a href="#" class="class-menu"><div class="line-menu elem-one"></div><div class="line-menu elem-two"></div><div class="line-menu elem-three"></div></a>
            <ul class="sousMenu">
                    <li><a href="idea.html">IDEA</a></li>
                    <li><a href="legend.html">LEGEND</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PRODUCTS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">WORK WITH US</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PRESS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><img src="elem/Btn-langue.png" alt="bouton-langue" class="menu-button bouton-langue" /></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><img src="elem/shopping-bag.png" alt="bouton-langue" class="menu-button bouton-langue" /></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><img src="elem/connexion.png" alt="bouton-langue" class="menu-button connexion" /></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><img src="elem/fb-insta.png" alt="bouton-langue" class="menu-button fb-insta" /></a></li>
            </ul>
     </li>
     </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if you don't want to use custom jquery code, just change all occurences of `.class-menu:hover` to `li:hover .class-menu`.

Then the `class-menu` would change anytime your `li` object is hovered, and since the menu is part of the `li` then you'll keep the mouse over it even if hovering other positions in the menu.